# create df that iterates thru row and columns

Tags: python, finance

I have the following df

```
columns = ['ON','1W','2W','3W','1M','2M','3M','6M','9M','1Y','2Y','3Y','5Y','7Y','10Y']

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns)

data = pd.DataFrame([8.6325, 7.3975, 9.    , 8.6275, 8.5   , 8.375 , 8.07  , 7.82  ,
       7.77  , 7.7   , 7.8   , 8.025 , 8.535 , 8.83  , 9.15  ])

new_df['Vols'] = data.values

new_df.rename(columns = {'Tenor': 'Vols'}, inplace = True)

new_df.columns = ['Tenor', 'Implied_Vol']

new_df = new_df.set_index('Tenor')

new_df
```

I'm trying to find the percent of each tenor, across tenors

I have the data as:

```
for ind in new_df.index:
    print(pd.DataFrame(new_df['Implied_Vol'][ind] / new_df['Implied_Vol']))
```

How do use above data to create a df that shows the implied vol as a % of each implied vol's tenor like below. This is what I expect it to look like

[image: expected df]

The data is there, but I'm not sure how to transform/iterate thru the data properly to create the final df

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

tenor = ['ON', '1W', '2W', '3W', '1M', '2M', '3M', '6M', '9M', '1Y', '2Y', '3Y', '5Y', '7Y', '10Y']
vols = [8.6325, 7.3975, 9.0, 8.6275, 8.5, 8.375, 8.07, 7.82, 7.77, 7.7, 7.8, 8.025, 8.535, 8.83, 9.15]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=[vols, tenor], columns=[vols, tenor])

for keys in new_df.index:
    for columns in new_df:
        new_df.loc[keys][columns] = keys[0]/columns[0]

print(new_df)
```